# Cleaner way to use simple if-else statements

Tags: c#, if-statement

My code currently has several simple if-else statements like the follwing:

```
if (notExists)
{
    return false;
}
else
{
    return true;
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to implement this logic?

Comment: What does that remark mean `Google for possible solutions`? Only interpretation I can think of is that you are requesting us to goole a possible solution.

Comment: @RandRandom Probably expressing the attempts OP made to find a solution for his/her problem ... Add a "d" to "Google" and the sentence makes much more sense ...

Comment: I tried to find a solution on google :)

Comment: Aside: This naming wouldn't pass a code review where I work - we don't allow "not" as a prefix for a boolean. It would either have to be the reverse condition "exists" or named something like "isMissing"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, why not simply?

```
return !notExists:
```

Or declare a variable `bool exists` instead to make it even more readable.

Comment: OP doesn't show it, but that seems not possible with `several simple if-else statements` as OP might exchange them with multiple returns eg. `return !notCool; return !notExists;` which will make the second return un-reachable

Comment: @RandRandom OP doesn't mention `else if` at all though.

Comment: @MatthewWatson - ah, I see what you are implying, as OP only uses `else` it will never reach a second `if-else` block, good catch

Comment: @RandRandom: I've understood it as OP has multiple methods with similar logic. "My code currently has", so not "My method ..."

Answer (score 0):

Or, maybe for readability and/or taste:

```
return notExists ? false : true;
```

Answer (score -2):

If there's one line of code between the braces you may remove them. Like this:

```
int x = -5;
if (x > 0) Console.WriteLine("Positive");
else if (x < 0) Console.WriteLine("Negative");
else Console.WriteLine("Zero");
```

Comment: Best to always use braces.

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't. Missing braces around the body of an `if` is a common reason for errors, especially if one isn't careful at refactoring.